# Pyqt multiprocessing index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error, multiprocessing, pool

Following the Python Standard Library By Example on multiprocessing, I am trying to do some calculations with multiprocessing, but get returned an index error.

The current structure is like so,

`main.py` has the application class and some functions for loading data
`run.py` is

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    import main
    main.show()
```

It calls the `show()` function in main to display the gui.  I used this method from other SO posts to stop multiple GUI from being shown.

Outside the GUI class I have these functions

```
def start_process():
    print 'Starting', multiprocessing.current_process().name

def multimanager(start,end):
    inputs=range(start,end) 
    non_multi = map(mymod.algorithm, inputs)
    print non_multi

    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,
                                initializer=start_process,
                                )

    pool_outputs = pool.map(mymod.algorithm,inputs)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print "Pool :", pool_outputs
```

I have noticed a few things.  According to the book, the `map()` function should act the same.  So the books example does the same mapping of inputs to function as the processing.  I have done that, and the  `non_multi = map(mymod.algorithm, inputs)` works.  However, the multiprocessing one does not.

If I change the `mymod.algorithm` to just +1 the input number, it seems to work.  Except, at no time does the `start_process()` function seem to be called, since it does not `print` `'Starting'`

Although the Pool does print the results for the basic addition algorithm, I am not sure it is really on different processes since the `start_process()` function does not seem to be called.

In the chance that it is, I am wondering if the algorithm does something not allowed by multiprocessing.  From a different SO post, an answer mentioned that this list index error in multiprocessing is not specific.  In case more information can help find the problem, the algorithm calls a global variable by importing a `globalvariable.py` file which stores an array of dictionaries.  The input to the map function is the index of the array, and in different functions the data is calculated with matrix operations and such, which then stores some data to the global variable.

Could this be a problem with the global variable I am using?  If so, is there a different way to pass the variable for each process? (The program is a bit large, so its not possible to just copy the variables into the `mymod.py` file.

The error is

```
File "C...main.py", line 71, in multimanager
    pool_outputs = pool.map(mymod.algorithm,inputs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Edit Additional info:

there is a class in a module `myclass.py`

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Mydata = None
```

a `globalvariable.py` file has a global variable array that stores the data classes

```
data = []
```

Both the `main.py` and the `mymod.py` import `globalvariable.py`.  In the `main.py` data is loaded, and each time, a class instance is created (`myclass.Data()`), this instance is then appended to the array `data` stored in `globalvariable.py`.  So before the processes are called, printing the global variable data would print

```
[<myclass.Data instance at 0x050F6878>,<myclass.Data instance at 0x050F6879>]
```

however, when the process starts, it prints as an empty array.

mymod.py looks like:

```
import globalvariable as gv

def algorithm(index):
    print gv.data
```

prints `[]`

I tried this with just basic variables as well and it did not work.  What is the way to have processes load the correct variables when started?  Note, I dont want to share between the process, just have each process start with the same data from the beginning.

Comment: Are you running this code in IDLE? That would probably explain why you're not seeing the output of the `print` statement you put in `start_process`. Run it directly from the Windows CLI and you'll probably see the output.

Comment: @dano yes i was using idle, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializer is called in the worker process. For their output to show immediately, you whould probably call `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print`.

In general, it is not a good idea to specifiy more worker processes then the return value of `cpu_count`.

The idea behind `multiprocessing.Pool.map` is that the workers get called repeatedly with values from the iterable. Since multiprocessing uses *multiple processes*, there are no globally shared variables.

When a worker is started, it has a *copy* of everything that was in the parent process. But with the exception of explicitly shared memory, (like `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Array`) those variables are *independant*.

My rule of thumb is that if the data that you want to send to the workers is small (up to a couple of kilobytes) use the iterable that you supply to the map function to send the data to the workers.

If the amount of data you want to send to each of the workers is large, write the data to a file or files, and sent the workers e.g. a tuple `('filename', offset, length)` so each worker can read the data that it needs using [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html).

Comment: When you refer to globally shared variables, are you saying that the process can not share a variable, or when the process starts it can not use predefined global variables.  I was trying to use the later.

Comment: @user1938107 Apart from things like shared memory, *processes* to not share variables. When you start a worker, that worker inherits a *copy* from the variables defined in the parent.

Comment: So if the main.py , where the worker is started, and the mymod.py, where the algorithm is, both import a globalvar.py file which contains the array, would that be considered variables defined in the parent?  Im sorry if im asking alot, but I am having trouble understanding when an import counts as being defined in that module

Comment: It has nothing to do with where it was defined. When you use a pool, Python creates *independant copies* of the parent process. They all have copies of the *same* data but they don't *share* it.

Comment: okay that is what i understood from you.  I dont try to make the processes share the same data, there are 4000 indexes in the array. this array is already defined.  each process takes one index of that array and calculates it.  they do not need any information from the others.  I will try some more debugging, thanks for the direction

Comment: Is that your `inputs`? What the Pool does when you call `map()` is iterate over that and send the items to the workers using a `Pipe`. In the worker your function is executed for every item coming in over the pipe and the return value is sent back to the parent over a `Pipe`.

Comment: my inputs is a range(start,end), which are indexes of an array that is stored in a globalvariable module.  Now that I can see the printouts from cmd (was using idle), the process is not getting the global data.  the file that it runs in imports the global data, but it is if it imports the original data and not the modified one